# Background image div clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div with a background image. How can i make the div (the background image) clickable? I want to unhide an other div when clicked on the div (image). Onclick code: `onclick="javascript:unhide('kazen')"`

```js
    var clickit = document.getElementsByClassName("fh5co-grid")[0];
      var kazen = document.getElementById("kazen");
    
      clickit.addEventListener("click", function(){
       if (kazen.style.display === "none") {
        kazen.style.display="block";
       } else {
        kazen.style.display="none";
       }
      });
    
      kazen.addEventListener("click", function(){
       this.style.display="none";
      });
```

```css
    #kazen {
      background-color: #cc9;
      display: none;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 15px;
      left: 15px;
    }
    
    .fh5co-grid {
    }
```

```html
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
             <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/PREVIEW_Shop_02-29.jpg);">
              <a class="image-popup text-center" >
               <div class="prod-title ">
                <h3>Kaas</h3>
                <h4>in ons aanbod hebben we verse en harde kazen - binnenkort meer hierover</h4>
               </div>
              </a>
             </div>
            </div>
    
            <div id="kazen" >
             <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/Melkerhei_Dag2-16-4.jpg);">
               <a class="image-popup text-center" >
                <div class="prod-title ">
    
                </div>
               </a>
              </div>
             </div>
    
            </div>
```

Comment: Just make `fh5co-grid` clickable

Comment: @Liam in the css?

Comment: $('.fh5co-gri').on('click', function() {unhide('kazen') }); -- jquery

Comment: Avoid inline javascript. Bad bad bad. Ugly. Pain to maintain.

Comment: @Snowmonkey what's a better solution?

Comment: Take a look below. My javascript is completely separate from the HTML, the event listeners are in the javascript, the functionality is completely transparent to the DOM itself. If the DOM changes, my listeners still work. By inline javascript, I mean that line in the OP's question, onclick="javascript..."

Comment: So you're using my answer, awesome, but you made one slight error -- kazen is hidden by default, and it contains the div that you need to click to display it.

Comment: So is that the behavior you're looking for? Have we answered your question?

Comment: It's good practice to combine variables in JavaScript. `var e = "hi", var j = "world!";`

Comment: Well, it's also good practice to not clutter the global namespace, @TyQ., but we've sort of stomped THAT sucker flat.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at the [fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/vd7useay/2/) I created if this is what you want.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.fh5co-grid").click(function() {
    $("div.next").css("display", "block");
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
  <div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(http://placehold.it/350x150);">
    <a class="image-popup text-center">
      <div class="prod-title ">
        <h3>cheese</h3>
        <h4>tekst</h4>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div style="background-color: #000; display:none" class="next">Next div</div>
```

Comment: Please add your code in answer. You can create an executable snippet here as well. (*Notice `<>` icon*)

Comment: If jsFiddle is blocked by someone's firewall, goes away, or is down, your answer has no value. Post the code here please.

Comment: Okay doing the same.

Comment: If you want to post a fiddle, it's never been a problem for me, but if at all possible, include an inline sample too. The only time it's been a problem is if the script gets TOO long, at which point the fiddle (or bin or codepen) makes sense.

Comment: I am sorry guys but I am having some problem in creating an executable snippet here. Added the code though.

Comment: Edited it to make functional. In the menu bar of your answer, there's a 'code' icon. Clicking on that will allow you to post working code samples.

Comment: Thanks @Snowmonkey

Answer (score 0):

From what you're describing, this seems pretty close. The background image isn't clickable, it's the div itself. And this could be done with jQuery, yes, but it's trivial enough that pure javascript is pretty easy here. Clicking in the red-boxed area will display the div with the id kazen, and clicking in either kazen or the red-boxed area again will hide it.

Note, there was a weird glitch to my solution. I changed the display if/else to check if it's currently displayed and hide it, rather than if it's currently hidden to display it. That was causing a strange effect of re-hiding the kazan div on the first click.

Within stackoverflow, you'll need an absolute url to display an image. If you aren't seeing your image here, that may be why.

```js
var clickit = document.getElementsByClassName("fh5co-grid")[0];
var kazen = document.getElementById("kazen");

clickit.addEventListener("click", function(){
  if (kazen.style.display === "block") {
    kazen.style.display="none";
  } else {
    kazen.style.display="block";
  }
});

kazen.addEventListener("click", function(){
  this.style.display="none";
 });
```

```css
#kazen {
  background: url("https://static.pexels.com/photos/6832/waterfall-beauty-lets-explore-lets-get-lost.jpg");
  background-size: 100%;
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.fh5co-grid {
  border: 1px dotted red;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 ">
<div class="fh5co-grid" style="background-image: url(images/PREVIEW.jpg);">
  <a class="image-popup text-center">
    <div class="prod-title ">
      <h3>cheese</h3>
      <h4>tekst</h4>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
</div>
<div id="kazen">
  Click me to hide!
  </div>
```

Comment: When you say still not working, what exactly are you saying? Does the div display?

Comment: div does not display, can't click on the image

Comment: In stackoverflow, a relative image url will break, and thus won't display. Also, I've edited the code in my answer, there was a display issue in my if/else statement. Try taking a look at the above code again, see if it's any better for you.